# Netbeans buiding Ant Project on Linux

Tags: linux, ant, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

There is a legacy project in our team, that has build.xml file, dist folder, nbproject etc in its project's folder structure. To build it on Linux machine they use Netbeans 8.2 IDE. There is no Ant installed on that machine I confirmed with ant -v command. I want to understand that :

1. Is Netbeans internally using ANT to build this project ?
2. If, yes then how ?
3. Where in Netbeans I can find the ANT configurations to proof/confirm that its ANT project and Netbeans internally using ant to build it.

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 is a bit outdated. You might want to consider upgrading to 12.0 (or 12.1) anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Ant is embedded in the Netbeans installation directory. On my Netbeans 11 it's in `<Netbeans_install_dir>/extide/ant`.
3. In Netbeans IDE, menu `Tools/Options/Java` and there should be an Ant tab which shows the current path to Ant -which can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans official [site](https://netbeans.org/features/java/build-tools.html) has described about the build tools it is using internally.
Regarding ANT it says:
*The default NetBeans IDE project system is built directly on top of the Ant build system. All of the project commands, such as "Build Project" and "Run File in Debugger", call targets in the project's Ant script.*